# Responsive Image Grid - Best Practices and Retaining Proportions

Tags: css, image, grid, less

I'm familiar with most concepts of responsive design. However, grids and gutters have me scratching my head a lot (most solutions I've found feel very 'hacky'). But this. THIS. Is bending my brain.

[image: Responsive Image Layout]

I want to create an image grid. It will have a maximum size, but all of the images will scale down in harmony when the viewport is resized. In doing so everything will keep the correct ratio (all perfectly square in this example).

Now I think this may be possible, if I declare a fixed height, but surely that then makes is completely unresponsive. For example I've created a quick (and really bad...but that's why I'm here!) [mock-up](https://jsfiddle.net/c138u75v/) of how that might....[I was going to say work].

```
<style>
body ,
html {
    height:100%;
}
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}  
.main-image {
    float:left;
    width:66%;
    height:200px;    
}
.alt-images {
    float:right;
    width:33%;
    height:200px;
}    
.main-image div {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:grey;
    padding:5px;
}
.alt-images div {
    height:33%;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
}    
.one {
    background-color:red;
}
.two {
    background-color:blue;
}
.three {
    background-color:green;   
}
</style>

<div>
    <div class="main-image">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="alt-images">
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="two"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's the point. Yes it's a bad example. I put it together quick. But quite honestly, I'm really struggling to put together a viable solution. Nothing I've tried yet DOES work.

What I'm really interested in here. Rather than you guys pulling apart my shoddy code up there. **Is the best way to approach this.** For example, is it a CSS only solution, or will I find life easier using Javascript. I'm using jQuery Masonry in my project too, and doing a bit of research, I think Isotope may offer some solutions, but I'd rather not go there is a cost to use it in commercial projects.

What's more. When the page scales down further and space becomes more limited. The layout will flip round and look like THIS:

[image: Additional Layout]

I think I'm going to bust a blood vessel!

Help.

Site-wide frameworks (Twitter Bootstrap, etc) are not an option. The project has already been started. I'm open to jQuery plugins though, and I'm using LESS with some very basic mixins for creating grids.

**How would you approach this problem? Is it really as difficult as it appears to me?**

Edit: Forgot to mention that it must work in IE9 (which doesn't support flexbox, amongst other things) and above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I would put the images as a background image as a cover image instead of inline in HTML.** I think that's the only way to retain the aspect ratio of the image while changing the aspect ratio of the containing div.

Cover Background Images:
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's the containing divs I'm having the real problem with though. I'm not sure I've explained myself well. Ideally, the aspect ratio of the containing divs would remain the same (unlike in my jsfiddle, which doesn't work! Hence me being here.). Also I forgot to mention, it must work in IE9 and above. So I think that rules out cover and flexbox. I see lots of people doing this...I just can't work out how.